# Using Dev.to API now only shows last 30 articles

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have been using Dev.to public API in my portfolio for almost 3 years, and it always used to show all of my articles on my portfolio. Recently I switched my entire portfolio to ReactJS and SaSS from native HTML, CSS and JS. And now, it only shows me my last 30 articles.

I am using the API as under

```js
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchArticles() {
            const response = await fetch(
                'https://dev.to/api/articles?username=mursalfk'
            );
            const data = await response.json();
            data?.map((article) => {
                const needed_data = {
                    title: article.title,
                    description: article.description,
                    url: article.url,
                    image: article.social_image,
                    date: article.published_at,
                    tags: article.tag_list,
                }
                setWriteUps(prevState => [...prevState, needed_data])
            })
        }
        fetchArticles();
    }, [])
```

Can anyone help me out with this one, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a **demo at this link**: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-pascal-oc6h0b?file=/src/App.js

**In your API you just received 30 objects. I've checked your portfolio link you also are receiving 30 objects. If you are expecting more than that, this problem is related to API**

> Attention that in your code you do not have the `needed_data` variable but probably this will receive the map I guess

#### Code:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

async function fetchArticles() {
  const response = await fetch("https://dev.to/api/articles?username=mursalfk");
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  return data?.map((article) => {
    return {
      title: article.title,
      description: article.description,
      url: article.url,
      image: article.social_image,
      date: article.published_at,
      tags: article.tag_list
    };
  });
}

export default function App() {
  const [writeUps, setWriteUps] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      (async function () {
        const articlesRespose = await fetchArticles();
        setWriteUps(articlesRespose);
      })();
  }, []);

  const WriteUps = writeUps.map((writeUp, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={writeUp.id}>
        <div>idnex array: {index}</div>
        <h3>{writeUp.title}</h3>
        <p>{writeUp.description}</p>
        <img
          alt={writeUp.title}
          style={{ width: "200px" }}
          src={writeUp.image}
        />
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="App">{WriteUps}</div>;
}
```